# How to assign one ostream pointer to another?

Tags: c++, vi

I'm trying to pass an `ostream` pointer address into a function and it keeps returning a pointer error. What would be a correct way of assigning (setting an `ostream` pointer?

The code :

Declaration in header file:

```
static ostream *out ;
```

Initialized in implementation file as:

```
ostream * Vehicle :: out = &cout;
```

ostream pointer "setter" function

```
void MotorVehicle :: setOut(ostream &o){

        out = &o;

}

void MotorVehicle :: print(){

        *out << name << make << model << mpg <<" ";
}
```

Inherited Class print functions

```
void Truck :: setcargoCapacity(){ //other assignments are done same. 

        cin >> cargoCapacity;

}

void Truck :: print(){

        *out << name << make << model << mpg << cargoCapacity << " ";

}

void Truck :: read(){

        cout << "Please enter cargo capacity for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setcargoCapacity();
        cout << "Please enter name for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setName();
        cout << "Please enter make for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setMake();

        cout << "Please enter model for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setModel();

        cout << "Please enter MPG for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setMpg();

}
```

Main Implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>
#include "motorVehicle.h"

#include "car.h"
#include "truck.h"


typedef vector<MotorVehicle *> vectorOfMotorVehicle;

using namespace std;

// prompt the user for the Vehicle type to create, and get the reply
string prompt(void);

int main() {
   vectorOfMotorVehicle v;    // or objects derived from MotorVehicles
   int           numVehicles = 0;  // denotes how many MotorVehicles we have
   string        reply;  // indicates type of MotorVehicle to build
   bool          error = false;    // set when a user response is in error
   string        outputLocation;   // where the output of print() will go
   ofstream     *out = NULL;
   MotorVehicle *m;


   m = new MotorVehicle("None");
   v.push_back(m);

   // chose where the output will go
   cout << "Where would you like the output?  ";
   cin  >> outputLocation;

   if (outputLocation == "stdout") {
      ; // no action to take, because stdout (i.e., cout) is the default
   } else if (outputLocation == "stderr") {
      v[0]->setOut(cerr);
   } else {
      out = new ofstream;
      out->open(outputLocation.c_str());
      if (out->fail()) {
         cerr << "Error:  error writing to " << outputLocation << endl;
         return 1;
      }
      v[0]->setOut(*out);
   }

   // get the type of Vehicle to create
   reply = prompt();

   // loop, reading vehicle descriptions, until a "quit" command is received
   while (reply != "quit") {

      // create the new MotorVehicle object and push it into the vector
      switch (toupper(reply[0])) {
        case 'T' : m = (MotorVehicle *) (new Truck);
                   v.push_back(m);
                   break;
        case 'C' : m = (MotorVehicle *) (new Car);
                   v.push_back(m);
                   break;
        case 'Q' : reply = "quit";
                   continue;
        default  : cerr << "Incorrect response\n\n";
                   error = true;
      }

      // if no error, then we have a new Vehicle to initialize via read()
      if (!error) {
         numVehicles++;
         v[numVehicles]->read();
      }

      // reset error flag, and request a new Vehicle type
      error = false;
      reply = prompt();
   }

   // report on what Vehicles were created to test read() and print()
   for (int i = 0; i <= numVehicles; i++) {
      //*out << "Vehicle " << i << endl;

      // print the Vehicle characteristics (attributes)
      v[i]->print();

      //*out << endl;

      // free the storage for this Vehicle
      delete v[i];
   }

   // if we opened an output file, then close it
   if (out != NULL) {
      out->close();
      delete out;
   }

   return 0;
}

// prompt the user for the Vehicle type to create, and get the reply
string prompt() {
   string reply;    // the user reponse to the prompt

   // prompt for and get user response
   cout << "\nWhich type of vehicle would you like to initialize"
        << "\n--car or truck (or \"quit\" to exit):  ";
   cin  >> reply;

   return reply;
}
```

What would be an ideal way to pass an `ostream` into a function and set it? When `*out` tries to print in main(), it crashes and returns a pointer error. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Off topic: you're doing something silly here. `std::vector` is being used without `std::`  in  `typedef vector<MotorVehicle *> vectorOfMotorVehicle;` is ahead of `using namespace std;. Which means you've probably placed a `using namespace std;` in a header. That's a nasty surprise for anyone including the header and expecting proper `std` namespace behaviour.

Comment: The possibilities for the cause of the problem you seek is almost limitless. [mcve], please.

Comment: I used gdb to debug and these were the only sections that could be returning the error so I tried to add minimal code.

Comment: Unrelated: `m = (MotorVehicle *) (new Truck);
                   v.push_back(m);` can be replaced with `v.push_back(new Truck);`.

Comment: Minimal you may have achieved. Complete you have not. I cannot reproduce your error with what you have given. Think on this: What are we supposed to do to figure out why you can't print without the print routine?

Comment: Here's one problem, maybe the only problem, you have:`for (int i = 0; i <= numVehicles; i++)`. `i` ranges [0,`numVehicles`]. `v` contains valid elements from [0,`numVehicles`). `v[i]->print();` and `delete v[i];` access out of range. The  `delete v[i];` is particularly fatal.

Comment: I have edited the code to show the print and read functions. Thanks you so much for the help!

Comment: You have missed the goal of the MCVE. What you want is to isolate the bug. Make a program that contains the bug and nothing but the bug. Bunch of reasons for this. If there is nothing but the bug, the bug is usually pretty obvious. The fix for the bug might might not be obvious, but oh well that's when you ask here. Next, if there is nothing but the bug, when you fix the bug, you can be pretty sure you fixed the bug. There probably isn't some other bug that makes you think you didn't fix the bug.